# Calling real method though given different answer to return on a static method execution

Tags: junit, mockito, powermock

I am using power mockito and I am mocking a class `SomeUtil` having all static methods.

```
import java.util.List;

class SomeUtil {

    // other static methods

    public static X createX(String name, List<String> addresses, boolean isEnabled) {
        // implementation
        return null;
    }

    // other static methods

}
```

And I have mocked it as follows.

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(SomeUtil.class, Answers.CALLS_REAL_METHODS.get());
Answer<Row> createXAnswer = new Answer<Row>() {
            @Override
            public Row answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
                return new X();
            }
        };
PowerMockito.when(SomeUtil.createX(Mockito.any(String.class), Mockito.any(List.class), Mockito.any(Boolean.class)).thenAnswer(createXAnswer);
```

But with that `createX()` method always invokes original method, which I am trying to avoid. I suspect that because of `boolean` **primitive** type. Am I missing something here? Please guide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have omitted some important annotations on your test class (`@RunWith`and `@PrepareForTest`). This is a complete example:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertSame;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.anyBoolean;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.anyList;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.anyString;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mockStatic;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.when;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.invocation.InvocationOnMock;
import org.mockito.stubbing.Answer;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(SomeUtil.class)
public class SomeUtilTest {
    @Test
    public void should_do_this() {
        mockStatic(SomeUtil.class, Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS);
        final X x = new X();

        when(SomeUtil.createX(anyString(), anyList(), anyBoolean())).thenReturn(x);

        assertSame(x, SomeUtil.createX(null, null, true));
    }
}
```

---

This example works but could in some case. For example if the `createX` raise an exception.  fail sometime because the **real method `createX` is invoked ** * when we stub it:

```
when(SomeUtil.createX(anyString(), anyList(), anyBoolean())).thenAnswer(createXAnswer);
```

this is due to the default answer `CALLS_REAL_METHODS`:

```
mockStatic(SomeUtil.class, Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS);
```

since the OP can't remove this default answer (see comment):

> For only few methods I want to return our own Answer. For the rest of methods I want to call real methods.

I think you will have to use powermock api:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertSame;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mockStatic;
import static org.powermock.api.support.membermodification.MemberMatcher.method;
import static org.powermock.api.support.membermodification.MemberModifier.stub;

import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(SomeUtil.class)
public class SomeUtilTest {
    @Test
    public void should_do_this() {
        mockStatic(SomeUtil.class, Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS);
        final X x = new X();

        stub(method(SomeUtil.class,
                "createX",
                String.class,
                List.class,
                boolean.class)).toReturn(x);


        assertSame(x, SomeUtil.createX(null, null, true));
    }
}
```

Comment: No! I have added those annotations!

Comment: Euh, i run my test and it works. May be, if you provide a [**SSCCE**](http://sscce.org/), i could help you

Comment: I have tested my simple example as well and working fine. But in my actual development code in that mocked API I am getting `NullPointerException`, as `PowerMockito.when(SomeUtil.createX(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyList(), Mockito.anyBoolean())).thenAnswer(createXAnswer);` invoking real method. In your example also please try doing some operation on a null value for which we have provided our own answer. You will also see `NullPointerException`.

Comment: This is the behavior of the parameter `Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS`? Do you really need it ?

Comment: For only few methods I want to return our own Answer. For the rest of methods I want to call real methods.

Comment: You will have to remove `Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS` from the global `mockStatic` and use `thenCallRealMethod` for the method you don't want to stub.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57139/discussion-between-pokuri-and-gontard).

Comment: @Pokuri Updated my answer. I hope it will help you