# Not able to understand how to go with PowerMockito in my scenario

Tags: java, junit, powermock

I have a Util class having 20+ static methods. I want to mock those static methods with `PowerMockito` and want to return my own `Answer` for 3 methods and for the rest of methods want to invoke real/actual methods. How to achieve that?

If do this way

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(RuntimeDocumentFactory.class, Answers.CALLS_REAL_METHODS.get());
PowerMockito.when(RuntimeDocumentFactory.createRow(Mockito.any(Zone.class), Mockito.anyString())).thenAnswer(new CustomAnswer());
```

Here before invoking my `CustomAnswer` it's invoking real method, which results in a `NullPointerException` due to real logic. So, please suggest how to go about mocking few static methods to use `CustomAnswer` and rest to invoke real methods.

Comment: Cant you split out the tests in such a way that the tests you dont have to mock and call the real method in the same test?

Comment: Try to replace `Answers.CALLS_REAL_METHODS` with something that doesn't call real methods - like `Answers.RETURNS_MOCKS`

Comment: @smk If I split and write the test-cases they will pass. But what happens when that code block, for which I have written test-case, calling Util class Non-mocked/mocked methods in future changes. In that case my test-case may fail

Comment: @Pokuri what is the problem with [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24676855/1594933) ?

Comment: @gontard I am able to address that issue with your answer. But with stub I am not able to use my custom answer. As per my business logic I have do some copying from passing parameters of stub method to other object. For that I need custom answer. Hope I am not confusing!

Comment: @Pokuri ok, i get it.